# Can not import module in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed 'dateparser' and import successfully in Anaconda Prompt but I can not import module from Anaconda's lib in Visual studio code. Previously it worked well.

```py
import dateparser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateparser'
```

Could you help me, please? Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Are you using anaconda interpreter in vs code?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select this answer as an answer if it helped to solve your problem to help close this question.

`Go to the interpreter selection at the bottom left in vs code` -> `select anaconda interpreter`